# Configuring WildFly to listen any address

Tags: wildfly-8

We have done this in older version by using -b 0.0.0.0. But when we set this address in WildFly it fails. What is the alternative method to do this in WildFly-8.2?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your configuration file in the following way.

```
<interface name="public">  
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>  
 </interface>
```

To

```
<interface name="public">  
        <any-address/> 
 </interface>
```

Comment: I am using domain mode of wildfly-8.2. I updated host.xml file with <any-address/> and started server but unable to access with ip address of my system. It is still available on localhost. Is there nay way to troubleshot this?